# Is there a way to combine texmod .tpf files into one "package" file?

Tags: guild-wars

So, I play a lot of Guild Wars, and I generally load it through texmod to get certain UI enhancements that make the screen a bit prettier. This works generally well, but it annoys me a bit that each time I load texmod, I need to select about five different .tpf files from a drop down list before I can run the game through the program with the enhancements I like.

Is there some way to combine .tpf files into one file to reduce the amount of times I need to click the screen? I ask this out of sheer laziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a direct answer, but this might save your some time and clicks.  I usually load three .tpfs, so in Texmod I click on the .tpf folder button, and then press 3.  This loads the third on the list, and bumps the mod in the second position into the third position.  Basically, you should just have to press the 5 key five times.

Might help!

Comment: I'm thinking this is probably the best answer out there, and it did at least make me aware of a shortcut I was previously unaware of. Thanks very much!